# AWS Route 53 with IPv4 IP address and different domain host

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, a-records

I am setting up Hosted Zones with Route 53 on AWS. My domain name is provided by a non-AWS provider. I updated the A-record for the record with the static IPv4 address provided by the domain name provider (with 'Alias Target' switched off). I also updated the Domain Name Servers entries at my domain name provider website with AWS's server entries. I waited for 3 to 5 hours for the DNS entries to stabilize. Now I am pinging my domain from laptop and it fails saying 'Request Timed Out'. May be I am missing something here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the domain name, it will be much easier to troubleshoot

Comment: I would be glad to share the domain name privately, if you could let me know a place where I can drop it (email, private message, etc.). Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: I worked with @DusanBajic and got it resolved. I am yet to get the intended stuff working, but that's a different issue. Sincere thanks to Dusan for helping me resolving the issue!

Comment: The solution/resolution was to turn the 'Alias Target' to 'On', and accept the default A name entry displayed by AWS (the first entry).

Answer (score 0):

So you need to ***add*** the NS records from the AWS HostedZone to your NS records for domain.com do not overwrite the records make sure to add. Thats all you would need to do you can check using:

```
dig NS domain.com
```

This should return the aws nameserver records if its working correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Dig entries do display my Amazon Name Server entries. I added back the non-AWS name server entries back in the configuration.  But, the ping does not work yet. I am going to wait for another day (as these are updates to authoritative DNS server entries) and see if things improve.

Comment: Didn't work. I waited for more than 24 hours, but no luck.